# Change color of selected element in react and set first one as default

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react

I am trying below code which i picked from stack only i am using this code to change color of selected item its working fine but i also want to set color of first element always selected once page load

```
                        var List = React.createClass({
                          getInitialState: function(){
                            return { active: null}
                          },

                          toggle: function(position){
                            if (this.state.active === position) {
                              this.setState({active : null})
                            } else {
                              this.setState({active : position})
                            }
                          },

                          myColor: function(position) {
                            if (this.state.active === position) {
                              return "blue";
                            }
                            return "";
                          },

                          render: function () {
                            return (
                              <div>
                                <li style={{background: this.myColor(0)}} onClick={() => {this.toggle(0)}}>one</li>
                                <li style={{background: this.myColor(1)}} onClick={() => {this.toggle(1)}}>two</li>
                                <li style={{background: this.myColor(2)}} onClick={() => {this.toggle(2)}}>three</li>
                              </div>
                            );
                          }
                        });
                        ReactDOM.render(
                            <List/>,
                            document.getElementById('app')
                        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this?

```
 getInitialState: function(){
                    return { active: 0}
                  }
```